# Retrieve different row from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

i hava a set of following tables

customer(cus_id,cus_name);

jointAccount(cus_id,acc_number,relationship);

account(acc_number,cus_id)

now i want to create a select statement to list all the jointAccounts, 
it should included the both customer name, and relationship.

I have no idea how to retrieve both different user name, is that possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes. I'm assuming you mean you want to get customer info for both sides of the joint account per your jointAccount table. Not sure what database you're using so this answer is assuming MySQL.

You can join on the same table twice in a single SQL query. I'm assuming you have not yet created your tables, as you have `cus_id` listed twice in the jointAccount table. Typically these would be something like `cus_id1` and `cus_id2`, which I've used in my sample query below.

**Example:**

```
SELECT c1.cus_id AS cust1_id, c1.cus_name AS cust1_name
     , c2.cus_id AS cust2_id, c2.cus_name AS cust2_name, j.relationship
  FROM customer c1 
 INNER JOIN jointAccount j 
    ON c1.cus_id = j.cus_id1
     , customer c2
 INNER JOIN jointAccount j 
    ON c2.cus_id = j.cus_id2
```

I haven't tested this but that's the general idea.

Comment: Hi, i think u're correct, but i have edited my question again..do u this if i want to join like this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM jointAccount a LEFT JOIN customer c ON a.cus_id = c.cus_id;
```

just replace the * with the name of the columns you need.

Comment: Yes but how to specify 2 diffrent customer? can you speficy clearer how to write the * ?